# Relationship between $\nabla\cdot n$ and the normal $n$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

If $k=\nabla\cdot n$, what is the geometric relationship between $k$ and $n$? 
In terms of size and direction?

Is it true that $n$ is an outward-pointing normal iff $k>0$ and $n$ is inward-pointing iff $k<0$?

Comment: Do you mean to say $k = \nabla N$?

Comment: Please take a moment to consider what *specific* question you want to ask.

Comment: I mean that "∇.N"

Comment: Are you assuming an implicitly defined surface here? I would use a local orthogonal coordinate system to see that $\nabla\cdot n$ is independent of the implicit surface  equation, and equals the sum of the two principal curvatures. This implies that your $k$ equals twice the mean curvature. I think $n$ must be outward-pointing normal if you want to get the "correct" sign for the mean curvature.

Comment: Mr.Klimpel I assume that the surface is a interface and k equals the mean curvature,no twice the mean curvature,but I dont know relationship between them!!! plz help me